# Hide navbar and sidebar on 'login page', but show them on other pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and couldn't solve this problem. When I click the log in button, it goes to the home page, but the navbar and sidebar stay at the log in page. how can i fix this problem? Can't I handle this problem without putting the navbar and sidebar inside other components?

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JwgK.png)

[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJzef.png)

Comment: Can you mention which route takes the user to login page?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Route path="/" element={<Login />}

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, do you want to display the sidebar and navbar only when it's not the login page and don't want to display them when you are on the login page?

Comment: yes what you said is correct. I don't want to see navbar and sidebar on login page. I just want to see it on other pages

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. I'll explain each part of the code.

First of all, import `useState` and `useEffect` from `react`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
```

Now, we have to know the current path of the webpage. For that, we use `useState` to set the current path.

In function `App()`, we initialize the `currPath` and set its initial value to the current path.

```
const [currPath, setCurrPath] = useState(window.location.pathname)
```

As per the behavior of `useEffect()`, it is called whenever the elements of the page are modified. We use it to get the current path whenever we go to the page with a different path, in other words, when the elements of the page are modified.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCurrPath(window.location.pathname)
}, [])
```

Now, every time we go to a different page, the `currPath` gets updated. As we only want to display **navbar** and **sidebar** whenever the `path` is *not* `/`, i.e. not the login path, we write it as:

```
{currPath !== '/' && <><SidebarNav /><Navbar /></>}
```

The above snippet comes right under the opening `<BrowserRouter>` tag.

**Note:** Multiple JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag and hence both `<SidebarNav />` and `<Navbar />` are wrapped inside `<>` and `</>`.

Comment: Thank you, technically it worked, but that's not enough. Because when I click the log in button, the navbar and sidebar do not appear on the homepage. When I refresh the page, the navbar and sidebar appear. What should I do to make it appear without refreshing the page?

Comment: I didn't quite get your question, are you saying that after refresh the sidebar and navbar appeared on the login page?

Comment: I'm on the log in page and I click the log in button. it redirects me to http://localhost:3000/home. I can't see the navbar and sidebar on the homepage. but when I refresh the homepage, the navbar and sidebar appear.

Comment: Yes, I understood it correctly now, can you share the snippet of code that redirects to the home page?

Comment: <Link to="/home"><button className="btn-login">Log in</button></Link>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not a good practice to use the root path "/" with the login page. you can update your App.js as the following:

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<AppLayout links={linksDetails} />}>
      <Route index element={<HomeDashboard />} />
      <Route path="shop" element={<ShopDashboard />} />
      <Route path="login"
        element={
            <LoginDashboard />
        }
      />
      <Route
        path="user-settings"
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute>
            <UserSettingsDashboard />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        }
      />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundDashboard />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
```

After that, in your AppLayout component (which contains Sidebar and Navbar) you can use the following;

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const AppLayout = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const isLoginPage = useMemo(()=> pathname.includes('login'), [pathname]);
...

{!isLoginPage  && <Navbar />}
```

In case you want to use the **same Routes** that you are using in your question, the condition will be the following:

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();

const isLoginPage = useMemo(()=> pathname === "/", [pathname]);
...

{!isLoginPage  && <Navbar />}
...
{!isLoginPage  && <Sidebar />}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey I just faced the same problem in next 13.

in my case i created a global layout that looks like this :

```html
<html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <div>
            {children}
          </div>
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
```

then i careated a folder and name it (folder) you can name it wathever you want. i put in the folder my dashboard dashbord then i created a new layout, take a look :

```html
<div className="flex">
      <SideBar />
      <div className={`w-[calc(100%-250px)] bg-[color:#EDF0F8] p-8`}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
```

In this layout where i put the , not in the global layout

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).